# Dirty errors with PHP popen()

Tags: php

I call a file with popen():

```
$fp = @popen("/usr/bin/openssl ...");
```

the specific details don't matter, but what happens here is that when I run the command I receive these errors on a Windows CMD:

> The system cannot find message text
>   for message number 0x3 in the message
>   file for System.

I know that the file don't exist on Windows, but why doesn't @ silence the errors? My library just tries a few different ways to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not [a error message issued by PHP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885275), so PHP's error suppression won't apply.

You'll have to check whether you can run the operation beforehand or suppress the output of system errors.

For suppressing, `2>NUL` should work, as you say. Wouldn't it be better though to test whether the file exists at all? On a Windows machine, your executable is most probably not located in `/usr/bin/openssl`.

```
if (file_exists("/usr/bin/...."))
 popen(".....");
```

Comment: How could I suppress the output of system errors? Editing my Windows settings?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I found:

I just wrote " 2>NUL" in the end of the CMD call to make all Windows errors to disappear.